# Redirecting pages to HTTPS in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, https

My site , when opened in Google Chrome, is giving error in all the site files , missing CSS files. If you look at the source code, all urls point to HTTPS. I've never done any configuration for HTTPS. Already looked into WooCommerce plugin and other plugins, but can not find the error. Can someone help me?

Site: http://isoflex.com.br

Comment: What's the site url value in WP options? How are included css files? Through functions.php or in static in header?

Comment: I guess the problem has already been figured out by you, and solved. As for me, it is opening properly here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. It was an outdated WooCommerce version for me. I just updated WooCommerce and it fixed it.

I see that you said you looked into WooCommerce, but are you using the most current version of WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with latest Chrome release and WooCommerce. Please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611247/wordpress-site-broken-adding-https-to-urls/31614841#31614841).