# Wordpress site broken adding https to urls

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, woocommerce

I've been notified that my Wordpress site is broken and the first thing I can tell is that it's broken cause it is automatically adding the https protocol to almost every link. So links, css, forms, everything is broken.

My site uses Woocommerce, but it wasn't configured to work with SSL, plus it was working fine.

**I've tried these things, but none of them brought functionality back:**

- Look for malicious code on files.
- Define and set SSL variables to false on wp-config.php
- Define Site's URL on wp-config.php
- Look at .htaccess
- Look for URLS with https on DB

My server doesn't have ssl and I'm not planning on using it.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue my site not working on chrome right now. I think it's cause by woo commerce. As i have disabled it site is working fine but I am still looking for right solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info, gonna try doing the same and see what happens

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress (WooCommerce?) forces https (when it shouldn't)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565155/wordpress-woocommerce-forces-https-when-it-shouldnt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Google Chrome it might be an issue.

Read that article I saw yesterday: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/

Comment: Wow, It is serious! I never would have thought that Chrome was the problem. Thanks for pointing it out, now i can solve it!

Comment: This show-stopper bug in chrome prevents me from logging in to StackOverflow with Chrome browser on Fedora 17.  Everything is forced to a version of HTTPS which is not supported on most sites.  This is why software must not be allowed to automatically self-update.  Sometimes it brings in show-stopper bugs that can't be undone.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because the latest Chrome version (**44.0.2403.89**) sends HTTPS: 1 in request headers, which force the Wordpress site to use https.

Follow up the bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=505268), it seems Chrome Dev team is working on it and hope they can fix it in next stable release by next Tuesday.

If you are using WooCommerce (most of the reports are from people who using it), you may want to consider one of these workarounds:

- Update to latest WooCommerce version, according to this [blog post](http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2015/07/woocommerce-2-3-13-security-and-maintenance-release/), they already fixed it on **2.3.13**
- Open `plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce.php` and comment out these lines

```php
if ( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'] ) ) { 
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS']; 
}
```